# Groovy read values from xml

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I have a [Sample Code](http://ideone.com/XM81w) where I'm trying to read data from an xml file and manipulating the values. This worked perfectly fine when I tried it on http://ideone.com

In my actual code I'm calling something like this

```
def xmlFile = "path/to/xmlfile.xml"
def tcproj = new XmlParser().parseText( getTemplate(xmlFile).toString() )
```

But when I use the same `if` condition specified in the Sample Code in my actual code, I get a completely different result.

On trying to debug I found that the result varied a lot. The result on my actual code with this when I tried to do

`println records.supported_versions.version.any { println it; it.toString().matches( /$ver/ ) }`

was this

```
version[attributes={}; value=[6.0.35.A]]
version[attributes={}; value=[7.0.25.B]]
false
```

When I do

```
println records.supported_versions.version.toString()
```

I get a result

```
[version[attributes={}; value=[6.0.35.A]], version[attributes={}; value=[7.0.25.B]]]
```

Can someone help me understand what's happening here and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `XmlParser` instead of `XmlSlurper` as in that example...

To use XmlParser, you need to change the code to:

```
class xmlWorker {
  static def tcproj = '''<tcs>
                           <supported_versions>
                             <version>6.0.35.A</version>
                             <version>7.0.25.B</version>
                           </supported_versions>
                         </tcs>'''
}
def records = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlWorker.tcproj)

def ver = "6.0.35.A"

println "Version: " + ver

println records.supported_versions.version.any {
  println it.text()
  it.text().matches( /${ver}/ )
}

if( records.supported_versions.version.any { it.text().matches( /${ver}/ ) } ) {
  println "if"
} else {
  println "else"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that answers my question. It doesn't solve my problem :(
I'm struggling to find out how to go about with the `if` condition.

Comment: @latestVersion Did you explain the problem in the question?  I can't see it :-(  What was the actual problem?

Comment: @latestVersion Can you add a bit to the bottom of your question expalining what you mean by _"...I'm struggling to find out how to go about with the if condition."_

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much. I actually missed what you had done. This is awesome. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @latestVersion No worries :-)  Good luck with it!